# Continuous Variable Entanglement Measure for the Statistically Mixed State

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

Can anybody tell me, which is the best entanglement measure for the Continuous Variable  Entanglement of a Statistically Mixed State ? 
I have read that Schmidt decomposition is not valid in this situation. Hence I cannot use von-Neumann entropy of the reduced density matrix. The system that I study has dissipation terms and the states are no longer statistically pure states.

Comment: Indeed, the von Neumann entropy of the reduced matrix is not an entanglement measure for statistically mixed states, since it is very high for the tensor product of two noisy states.
In general, entanglement measures for statistically mixed state are plenty and have different physical meaning (e.g. entanglement of distillation is not the entanglement of formation, which is not the negativity, an so on.). So, your question does not have a single valid answer, because we do not know enough on your system and why you want to look at it's entanglement.

Comment: So a few questions : are you interested in the entanglement of a 2-mode system or a bigger one ? Do you want an entanglement witness or an entanglement measure ? Are your state supposed to be Gaussian or not ? Depending on your answer to these question, the answer could be different.

Comment: But if you only want a simple to compute entanglement measure, (logarithmic) [negativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negativity_%28quantum_mechanics%29) is your friend

Comment: Dear Frédéric Grosshans thanks for the fast response. My system is a two coupled harmonic oscillator with dissipation. Evolution of the density matrix can be modeled by a Linbald Equation. But the states are no longer statistally pure. My states are also non-gaussian, I study continuous variable entanglement. I have found that the logarithmic negativity is valid in dimensions less than six. Since the states are non-gaussian  I cannot use covariance matrix method to find the negativity.

Comment: My research is exploring the connection between entanglement and classical chaos. Chaos is at its best when the system is dissipative then the quantum entanglement is complicated !!!

Comment: It depends what you call valid. Logarithmic negativity always detect free (i.e. distillable) entanglement. But in high dimension, you have bound (i.e. undistillable) entangled states. These are entangled state with 0 log-negativity. But log-negativity is not invalid, since a non-zero negativity really means there is some entanglement, even in high dimension. Finding a “valid” entanglement measure, (detecing all entangled states) is essentially hopeless, since the probleme of entanglement detection has been linked to th NP problem.

Comment: By the way, a review on entanglement measures is here : http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504163